# Science fiction novel where a human becomes smarter after touching an alien artifact

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book not long ago, though I'm unsure when it was published. In it humans had spotted an alien object in another region of the galaxy, and set off to investigate. Upon touching it, the main character was somehow changed. His brain became faster, and as a result he grew smarter.  At one point, he tries to communicate via a much more efficient language that he'd just made up, consisting of numerous tones and chords. The only othe thing I can recall is several people trying to destroy the earthbound end of a space elevator. Someone please say you know what the heck I'm talking about, because this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 11):

This is "[Count to a Trillion](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10999916-count-to-a-trillion)" by John C. Wright.

[image]

> The chance to help usher in that future comes when Montrose is
>   recruited for a manned interstellar mission to investigate an artifact
>   of alien origin. Known as the Monument, the artifact is inscribed with
>   data so complex, only a posthuman mind can decipher it. So Montrose
>   does the unthinkable: he injects himself with a dangerous biochemical
>   drug designed to boost his already formidable intellect to superhuman
>   intelligence. It drives him mad.

[This review](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf1032) mentions the creation of a novel language by the hero (after becoming exposed to an alien artifact) and the official [Google Books preview](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E2mhdKp0XS4C&pg=PA403&lpg=PA403&dq=%22Count%20to%20a%20Trillion%22%20and%20space%20elevator&source=bl&ots=eJfucd1ua2&sig=c_P4O5zUKbwEQ-9C56mep79mIhg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-e3RVOSbEJKt7Aap9YDgAw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Count%20to%20a%20Trillion%22%20and%20space%20elevator&f=false) refers to an assault on a space elevator.

Comment: Oh, that is exactly it! Thank you thank you!

Comment: @Jim - Don't forget to upvote and mark this as accepted :-)